# How do I switch between two created brushes without pressing N?

Tags: interface, texture-painting, quick-favorites

like we have in Photoshop and other digital art tools, we can press alt or some keybindings to change between the various brushes we have, how to do that in blender

Comment: Shift Spacebar is a shortcut to the tools, then you can choose the brush or press a numpad key

Comment: if you don't like the default shortcuts for the brushes you can change them anytime in the context menu (right-click on the icon) or add the brush selection to the Quick Favorites menu and use then the Q key.